# CakePHP Model Query Construction

Tags: cakephp

Hi I just started with CakePHP, and am wondering how to do a certain find query.

Basically I have a model called User that has a hasMany relationship to another model called roles. I want to essentially execute an SQL call along the lines of:

SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM roles
WHERE user_id = users.id
)

But also get the hasMany related data as well.

But am having trouble figuring out what is the best way to do this in CakePHP, outside of writing the MySQL out directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ehtesham: it's better to use [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable)
To find a user and related role records:

> ```
> $this->User->find('first',array(
>     'conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$some_id),
>     'contain'=>array('Role')
> ));
> ```

"SELECT * FROM users WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM roles WHERE user_id = users.id )": If I understand you correctly, you want to find all users that have at least 1 role? If so, you should set up [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count) and add one more condition to the find `'User.role_count >'=>0`

Comment: certainly if you just want to pull from only roles table. but what if user has other associations and that needs to be pulled as well.

Answer (score 0):

in users controller

```
  $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 'Role.user_id'), 'recursive' => 1));
```

Specifying recursive 1 will pull all related data as well

Comment: hmm with this I seem to be getting no results at all, despite the above MySQL query returning 8 rows.

Comment: there was a mistake, Model names must be singular i.e. User instead of Users. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Its very ambiguous, do you want to get all users having specific roles?

Comment: sorry I was vague--all users that have one or more role rows in the roles table

Comment: well if a user has many roles then I guess a single role might belongs to more than 1 user. If that is the case it should be a HABTM association not hasMany, try this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM.

Comment: each role belongs to only one user